# ADF - Unable to Parameterize in Linked Service to connect to Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

We have multiple databases on the same server (running in the same Azure region as ADF).  I would like to parameterize the database name in the connection.

When trying to follow along to [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/parameterize-connections-to-your-data-stores-in-azure-data-factory/) to connect to Azure SQL Database, I am unable to successfully connection to database when introducing dynamic content via a parameter.  Connection test works if I remove the param and put the database name string in its place.

Note, the Azure SQL Database firewall is set to **true** for `Allow Azure services and resources to access this server`.  Also using the AutoResolve IR.

Any ideas why this is not working?

**Error Received:**

[image]

**Parameter Setup:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Due to you can connect successfully by hardcode, there is something wrong with Parameterize in Linked Service.

Please make sure the VALUE of dbname is same with your the value of hardcode.

[image]

Then change `@linkedService().dbname` to `@{linkedService().dbname}` and refresh your page to have a try.